# Not being able to pull in a git hook (bash script)

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, githooks

I am working on a website, on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. When I push code to my website, I want my hook to automatically `pull` the code in my apache folder. The following commands update my website to the repository's current master without any issues:

```
cd /var/www/www.foo.net
git pull
```

My `post-update` hook is what should automatically do this, but I keep getting the same error every time I to push. Note that the push is executing correctly every time. The script looks like this (irrelevant code left out):

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $1)
case "$BRANCH" in
"somebranch")
        echo "You are pushing to somebranch!"
        cd /var/www/www.foo.net
        pwd
        git pull
        ;;
esac
```

In my opinion, this looks like it should work, especially considering that the debug output is what I am expecting it to be. Yet it does not work. I always get the following output:

```
remote: You are pushing to somebranch!
remote: /var/www/www.foo.net/
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Note how it reports that it is in the correct directory and that, as I said above, I am able to pull in that directory without issue. `/var/www/www.foo.net/` **is** a git repository.

I have also tried using `( cd /var/www/www.foo.net/ ; git pull )` but to no avail. I also don't think it can have anything to do with permissions; I am using Gitolite, and am able to pull to the local repository by using the account that's setup with Gitolite.

Any ideas? I'm having no joy at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if /var/www/www.foo.net/ is a valid git repo try

```
git --git-dir=/var/www/www.foo.net/.git --work-tree=/var/www/www.foo.net pull
```

This should result in FF pull.

Comment: That did it indeed! Do you know why the other thing didn't work?